# select all children with attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, xls

how can I get all children that have **any** (not specific) attributes in xpath or xsl?

e.g:

```
<person id= "11">
        <name>A name</name>
        <language lang="en">Hello</language >
        <country region="Africa">Egypt</country>
        <date-of-birth>2002</date-of-birth>
</person>
```

And I want to get back:

```
<language lang="en">Hello</language >
<country region="Africa">Egypt</country>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `/person/*[@*]` then you select the child elements of the person element that have at least one attribute.